# Specify base URL for Angular ClientApp served from ASP.NET Core WebApi

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've created an ASP.NET Core project which serves an Angular app using `services.AddSpaStaticFiles()`, `app.UseSpaStaticFiles()`, `app.UseSpa()`, etc.

But it serves the application directly from `http://localhost:1234`, while I want to serve it from `http://localhost:1234/angular/MyAngularApp1/`, while I want to use `http://localhost:1234/` for an API controller.

How can I achieve that?

**Note:** I need it to work in a production build. Some solutions appear to work, but in reality they work only when you run the site from Visual Studio, and stop working once you publish/deploy to IIS or Kestrel.

Comment: can you explain the usecase for this approach? we have the api on one port and the angular app on the other (with cors policy on the api of course),
on production the api runs in a subdomain

Comment: @DaniëlTulp, Sure - our production build has to accessed from within a network that is firewalled. Clients in the network can't access our app directly, but there is a reverse-proxy that was setup using IIS and URLRewrite to rewrite requests that start with a particular prefix. Any request that doesn't start will be dropped by the proxy. We don't have access to reconfigure that proxy so....

Answer (score 4):

Eventually I found a function that pretty much achieves this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UsePathBase("/MyPrefix/");

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    .......
```

See https://www.billbogaiv.com/posts/net-core-hosted-on-subdirectories-in-nginx for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a base url for your application like this

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "ClientApp/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify base URL for view from Angular ClientApp folder , try to set `href` attribute of `base`  by going to **ClientApp** > **src** > **index.html** like below :

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>ClientApp</title>
 <base href="/ClientApp">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
         app.Map(new PathString("/MyPrefix"), appMember =>
         {
             appMember.UseSpa(spa =>
             {
                 spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                 if (env.IsDevelopment())
                 {
                     spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                 }
             });
         });
```

and for API

```
app.Map("/api", api => 
    {
        api.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:5000/openid"
        });

        api.UseMvc();
    });
```

So you can run multiple parallel pipeline in same application. Read more about it [here](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/04/running-multiple-independent-asp-net-core-pipelines-side-by-side-in-the-same-application/)